# I'm making a Match making system in roblox, but for some reason the game manager breaks after the 1st round

Tags: lua, position, roblox

So I'm making this match making system in roblox, the way how it goes is 3 players for two teams, if either team scores then the teams will swap roles and begin a new round, in general the game manager works in its initial round, the problem occurs after the start of the 2nd and next consecutive rounds.

My problem specifically is this function:

```
local Defenders = {"Defending1","Defending2","Defending3"}
local DIndex = 1
local function SetBlue(player)
    if player.Team == Teams.Defending then
        local char = player.Character
        local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
        if hum then
            --DIndex = 1
            hum.RootPart.CollisionGroup = Defenders[DIndex]
            char.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = game.Workspace.Blue:FindFirstChild(Defenders[DIndex]).CFrame
            print(player.Name .. " is a defender with collision group " .. Defenders[DIndex])
            DIndex = DIndex % #Defenders + 1 -- increment the index
            RoundManager.DefenderAbility()
        end
    end
end
```

(I'm fairly new, so any feedback also helps!)
This function is supposed to assign the defenders a collisionGroup and teleport them to their individual patches, this is like checkpoints that they have to guard, and defend from the other team, this works on the initial round and flows just as intended.

Only problem is once the next round commences, regardless if the offensive team manages to score or not, the defenders are teleported to different parts of the area, for example the defenders are still given the defenders1, defenders2, defender3 Collision Group, and there is no duplicate among them, but they are teleported into the wrong patches, defender1 is teleported to defender3's spot, defender2 is teleported directly into the scoring area and defender3 is stuck free falling outside the map, he is also suspended in the air not moving.

I need help, here is how it is executed as a whole:

```
while true do
    task.wait(2)
    if #Players:GetPlayers() >= RoundSettings.MaxPopulation/2 then
--Everything works perfectly fine at this point
        if not FirstRound and not OngoingMatch then
            RoundManager.GoalCross()
            print("Giving players Abilities!")
            task.wait(RoundSettings.TransitionTime)
            print("Match Starting!")
            RoundManager.HasScored()
            RoundManager.CheckIfServerHasGoaled()
            RoundManager.TurnOver()
            FirstRound = false
            OngoingMatch = true
            DIndex = 1
            --RoundManager.WinCons()
--Things go haywire as soon as the elseif executes
        elseif not FirstRound and OngoingMatch then
            task.wait(RoundSettings.IntermissionTime)
            for i, player in pairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
                SetBlue(player)
                SetRed(player)
            end
            DIndex = 1
        end
    else
        print("Waiting for players to join!")
    end
    
end
```

I believe it has something to do with the TurnOver but I am not sure since this bascially just changes the players and the teams scores at the end of each round.

```
function RoundManager.TurnOver()
    local ScoreA = teamAScore
    local ScoreB = teamBScore

    teamBScore = ScoreA
    teamAScore = ScoreB
    
    --Swap Players in Team A to Defending Otherwise they are crossing again
    for i, player in ipairs(TeamA) do
        if player.Team == Crossing then
            player.Team = Defending
        else
            player.Team = Crossing
        end
    end
    --Swap Players in Team B to Crossing Otherwise they are defending again
    for i, player in ipairs(TeamB) do
        if player.Team == Defending then
            player.Team = Crossing
        else
            player.Team = Defending
        end
    end
end
```

What i want to happen is after the first initial round, I want to execute the turnover function, this would swap the current players in teamA and teamB, then after a small time, i want the defenders to be teleported into their correct defending areas, i want this to work until a team reaches or manages to get 3points.